# How to code an auto-increment counter in LaTeX

Tags: programming

When typesetting letters is common practice to have a reference such as:

```
   XXX-yl-0001
```

Where the last number is incremented for each successive letter. Normally, I hand-code the number. When having hundreds of letters one tends to now and then make mistakes and duplicate or miss references.

Can someone propose a method to automate this with TeX? Important is to only increment once for each run, i.e., you don't want the counter to increment if you re-run the file. Please note I am out of inspiration for a MWE.

My suggestion, is probably one needs two files. The first one to totalize and a local per jobname to keep the specific letter reference.

Comment: The easiest way is to put the number in the filename and then access it with `\jobname` and leave your editor the job of allocating a new file for each letter

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am trying to avoid deciding or typing the number in any form:)  Currently I have a web interface with old php doing it for me but I want to retire it, as it is not very practical.

Comment: you wouldn't type the number but (assuming you use emacs) M-x new-letter could just look around the disk and invent a new filename by incrementing the number from the highest found, then open the buffer on the new file.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't use EMACS and even if I did, my secretary would never figure it out. Idea behind the question is that one can save it under any name but the command say `\OurRef` would insert the right number.

Comment: If all letters of a certain project are stored in the same directory, and you _never_ compile an old letter again, then define an aux-file, say `<jobname>.no`. Then run (Lua-)LaTeX to get the jobname.no file and let Lua or TeX count the number of the *.no files in this directory and you've got your number after the second run.

Comment: @KeksDose Thanks. They get recompiled, now and then. Imagine you have sent letter with Ref: 1226 named ZZZZ, then you added a file AAAA, system will fail, you need to preserve the state as it was when the file was compiled first time.

Comment: I think a `.bat` for keeping the number somewhere and generating a template `.tex` file is safer. There should be no macros or variables that hold the number in the TeX file itself instead it should be hard coded for archive purposes. Hence I would look for a automated file generation solution which can be double clicked by your secretary.

Comment: @percusse ...Turing completeness! We as a community will accept that this is not solvable via TeX?

Comment: @YiannisLazarides If you recompile a letter and it should have the same reference number as when it was compiled first, then put the number of the *.no-files in your directory into the jobname.no file with the first run and make an "if": if there is a jobname.no file, take the reference number from there.

Comment: @KeksDose ...Have difficulty to understand how your proposal can be termed automated.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides Redundancy and fault-tolerance is not part of the definition of Turing completeness. Better safe than (CS)orry. Loosing an archive can easily be one of the saddest things.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: Does my answer do what you are looking for?

Comment: @Aditya Yes it does. New years resolution, get proficient in ConTeXt. I am envious. In the meantime I have hacked a LaTeX solution based on the two files. Will post it a bit later.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: Thanks. I was asking because I was not sure if I understood the question correctly or not.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a ConTeXt based solution. It uses datasets, which is the ConTeXt mechanism for multi-pass data. The basic idea is to store the MD5sum of the file and the count of the letter in the auxiliary file. At each run compare the stored value of MD5sum with the current value. If the md5sum has changed, increment the number and store it in the auxiliary file. Of course, if you delete the auxiliary file, the number is reset to zero. (For simplicity, I assume that the file suffix is always `.tex`)

```
\definedataset[letterdata]

\startluacode
  local datasets = job.datasets
  local filename = environment.inputfilename .. '.tex' -- temp hack
  local checksum = file.checksum(filename)

  local set = "letterdata"

  datasets.setdata{
    name = set,
    data = { checksum = checksum }
  }

  local oldsum  = datasets.getdata(set, 1, "checksum", "")
  local number  = datasets.getdata(set, 2, "number", 0)

  if oldsum ~= checksum then
    number = tonumber(number) + 1
  end

  datasets.setdata{
    name = set,
    data = { number = number }
  }


  context.setvalue("letternumber", number)
\stopluacode

\starttext

Value: \letternumber

\stoptext
```

This will increment the number whenever you change the file and recompile. Recompiling the same file will not increment the number.

Comment: I like your solution and will accept it as the correct answer. I will do this a bit later as I want to see if there are any comments to my solution.

Answer (score 2):

Quick LaTeX hack. Maybe not as elegant as the ConTeXt solution proposed by Aditya. Uses two streams. One keeps the totals and another caches the value of a letter.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\newcounter{total}
\setcounter{total}{1000}
\def\autoinc{%
        \newread\inputstream
        \immediate\openin\inputstream=\jobname.lcl
        \immediate\read\inputstream to \auxcommand
        \immediate\closeout\inputstream
    \gdef\OurRef{XXX-XX-\auxcommand}

}
%% First we check if a file with the jobname exists holding the RefNumber
%% If it does not exist increment the totalizer and write to file
\IfFileExists{\jobname.lcl}{\autoinc}{%
%% Read totals from file
        \newread\inputstream
        \immediate\openin\inputstream=autoincrementtotals.lcl
        \immediate\read\inputstream to \auxcommand
        \immediate\closeout\inputstream
    \setcounter{total}{\auxcommand}        
    \stepcounter{total}
%% Update totals file
    \newwrite\tempfile
    \immediate\openout\tempfile=autoincrementtotals.lcl
    \immediate\write\tempfile{\thetotal}%
    \immediate\closeout\tempfile

    \gdef\OurRef{XXX-XX-\thetotal}
    %% write to jobname.lcl
    \newwrite\tempfile
    \immediate\openout\tempfile=\jobname.lcl
    \immediate\write\tempfile{\thetotal}%
    \immediate\closeout\tempfile
}
\OurRef
\end{document}
```

Needs a bit more error checking and is good to go. One could also extend to cache the date as well of the letter based on this method.

Comment: Doesn't LaTeX have a standard means of storing variables in the `.aux` file for storing multi-pass data? Why store the variable in a separate auxiliary file

Comment: @Aditya It does, but is the first file people wipe out, as well if you need to LaTeX twice LaTeX will override it. In this case both the totals as well as the particular letter ref needs to be cached. Although one can use the .aux this way also you only need only one pass.

Comment: Ah, now I see what you actually wanted. Your letters are different TeX document. I was assuming that you edit the same tex file to create an updated reply. My solution is not appropriate for your situation.

Comment: @Aditya Oops! I skimmed over your code and thought was ok:)